# groupBy : how to recreate a canceled substream?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

In akka-stream `Flow`, there is the groupBy operation:

> This operation demultiplexes the incoming stream into separate output
>   streams, one for each element key. The key is computed for each
>   element using the given function. When a new key is encountered for
>   the first time a new substream is opened and subsequently fed with all
>   elements belonging to that key.

I tried to reuse a canceled substream, but it's not recreated…

Do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: Could you share your code to better explain your issue?